# WPF - How to simulate mouse over in preview

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

is there a way to simulate the mouse over when in VS preview?
I want to check my styling without 'build and run' every time.

Comment: Dont think there is something like a "live preview" in the XAML Editor. Seems like you have to build it ...

Answer (score 1):

No.

Because `MouseOver`event ***is not only for styling***, what if on mouse over,  app connects to DataBase and make some changes in there.

If you want to see, for example, the button background change or border brush or something like that, look at button properties section.